# Mouse click doesn't work, but pointer works

Tags: 16.04, unity, mouse

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and accidentally uninstalled `python2` and everything that depends on it. *Edit: According to `/var/log/apt/history.log`, 326 modules were removed: [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/raw/9GAiMMFm) (sorted alphabetically).*

I've reinstalled `python2` now but apparently a lot of things are still broken. Most urgently is obviously getting a functioning mouse back.

- When I boot my computer, I arrive at my normal desktop. Keyboard and mouse pointer work just fine, but **the mouse buttons only work in the launcher** -- not on the desktop and not in any launched apps.
- I can use the mouse to launch a terminal, then type `unity --replace &` into a terminal (as advised in [older posts](https://superuser.com/a/143957/9350)). Having done that, the mouse now works *inside* the terminal window but not on the window frame *nor anywhere else!*
- I can Ctrl+Alt+F2 and run `unity --replace &` from there. That appears to end the command I had running in the previous step, and when I go back to Ctrl+Alt+F7 then the mouse is working normally - but Unity's top menu bar (including the clock and system/power button) is blank.

It's a Logitech wireless mouse (M705) and I have put in a pair of fully charged batteries just to be sure and rule out the hardware.

--> What am I missing, and how do I restore my mouse clicks to normal operation without the `unity` workaround?

Comment: Removing `python2` removed also all packages which depend on it. Just reinstalling `python2` does not reinstall these packages. You should check in `/var/log/apt/history.log` which packages have been removed and reinstall them manually. I believe, this is a long list. Maybe someone here can provide a script to do that, but that's above my skills. Is this `python2.7` which you removed accidentally?

Comment: Do mouse keys work? (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html)

Comment: I don't understand how the mouse buttons depend on Python. @mook765 I added a []pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/raw/9GAiMMFm) above that lists the removed modules. Do you recommend that I reinstall ALL of them, or any in particular?

Comment: I cant' help you much with that. Fact is that removing python2 removed a lot of packages and after that you are facing problems. I don't know which of these packages are relevant for the mouse. I would reinstall all of them, just to make sure that you will not face other issues in the future. It might be a bit ugly work to do that manually, but to be honest, what choices do you have? If a complete reinstall is an option for you, that might be less time-consuming. That's life, accidents happens. Always be careful when running with root-privileges.

Comment: @mook765 you're absolutely right. And I am considering a reinstall, just to be sure. I'll first see how much trouble it is to reinstall the modules. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar with another package and partially took down my desktop.  Wouldn't accept any keyboard or mouse inputs.  I had to ssh in from another computer to implement the repair (probably could have booted into text mode as well).

I found this handy line somewhere; on this site I think:

```
sudo apt-get install `grep Remove /var/log/apt/history.log | tail -1 | sed -e 's|Remove: ||g' -e 's|([^)]*)||g' -e 's|:[^ ]* ||g' -e 's|,||g'`
```

Basically creates a list of all the removed packages and reinstalls them.  Just run the grep part first to get a sense of what will be reinstalled.